# My pointer/addresses are wrong no matter what I try

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Here is what I'm trying:

```
int a,b;
int *ptr;

a = 123;
ptr = &a;
b = *ptr;

printf("&a is %p\n",&a);
printf("ptr points to %p\n",ptr);
printf("&ptr is %p\n",&ptr);
printf("&b is %p\n",&b);
```

Results in:

```
&a is 0x7ffee01fc828
ptr points to 0x7ffee01fc828
&ptr is 0x7ffee01fc818
&b is 0x7ffee01fc820
```

I expected &b to show the same address as &a... But that's not the case, so I tried:

```
int a,*b;
int *ptr;

a = 123;
ptr = &a;
b = ptr;

printf("&a is %p\n",&a);
printf("ptr points to %p\n",ptr);
printf("&ptr is %p\n",&ptr);
printf("&b is %p\n",&b);
```

This still results in an unexpected memory address for &b:

```
&a is 0x7ffee1cbd828
ptr points to 0x7ffee1cbd828
&ptr is 0x7ffee1cbd818
&b is 0x7ffee1cbd820
```

Can someone help me understand why I'm unable to get &b matching the same address as &ptr or &a?

Thanks!

Comment: you're comparing pointers to pointers... drop the `&` you'll see the same value

Comment: Because in C, *no two different objects have the same address*. Pointers are objects, too. They are not the same as the thing they point at, just like an envelope is different from the house whose addres is printed on it.

Comment: Remember a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored in memory, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. If you need the value stored at the memory address `b` points to, you *dereference* `b` using the unary `'*'` operator, e.g. `int c = *b;` will initialize `c = 5`).

Comment: @rici: Unlike most other programming languages, pointers in C are *actual memory addresses,* not objects. They're neither the envelope nor the house.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- pointers are objects in the sense that a pointer is a location in memory that holds some value. [That is what C objects are.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15)

Comment: @robert: in C, an *actual memory address* is a value, and an object is simply the storage which holds a value. So I guess that's not like "most other languages" in which addresses are not first-class values. In a pointer-free language like Java, the envelope is an implementation detail and only the house has semantics. In C (and other languages) the envelope is visible and has semantics independent of the addressed house, so both the envelope and the house exist and you need to avoid confusing them with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected &b to show the same address as &a…

Having that expectation means, that you have a wrong mental model about how pointers work and what their semantics are in the C programming language. The key misconception seems to happen at these two lines of the original code fragment:

First you have

> ```
> b = *ptr;
> ```

This line translates into *"copy the contents of the memory at address `ptr` into the variable `b`." The variable `b` never even gets into contact with the pointer itself. You could rewrite it perfectly fine to the same effect into

```
int tmp = *ptr;
b = tmp;
```

As a matter of fact, every modern C compiler out there will produce identical code for either case.

The second line where you have a misconception is this one

> ```
> printf("&b is %p\n",&b);
> ```

specifically the effects of taking the address of the variable `b`, i.e. the result of `&b`. `b` is a completely independent variable, with its very own address. *This address cannot be changed!* The only thing that can be changed about a variable is its value.

Pointers are variables, too, and yes, a pointer does have an address itself. The value of a pointer is the address it points to. But like every variable, you cannot change the address where the variable is stored and when you assign an address to a pointer, you are changing its value. Hence when in your second code snipped you assign `b = ptr;` you're copying the *value* of `ptr` to `b`. After that, both `ptr` and `b` point to the same address, but these two pointers are two independent copies of the same value, where each copy is placed at a different place in memory. Naturally taking the address of `b` yields something different as the address of `ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for going into depth to explain the misunderstanding I had. The class I'm taking on linkedin learning is limited when they explain these things, so I'm figuring it out by trial, error, and stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

now `a`,`b` and `ptr` are 3 different variables (regardless of their type)

So their *address* is different. You'll have the same values by *not* taking the *address* of pointer variables.

```
int a,*b;
int *ptr;

a = 123;
ptr = &a;
b = ptr;

printf("&a is %p\n",&a);
printf("ptr points to %p\n",ptr);
printf("b is %p\n",b);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Really appreciate you taking the time and being succinct.